# PostgreSQL array_agg(INTEGER[])

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using Postgres 9.5, I want to concaternate integer arrays from a GROUP BY. From the documentation is seems as though array_agg should be able to do this, but I get: `ERROR:  cannot accumulate arrays of different dimensionality`

Using array_dims on my test set I get [1:18], [1:24] and [1:48]. I see this as 3 1-dimensional arrays of different lengths. The result should be a single array with dimension [1:90] What am I missing here?

Comment: IIRC array_agg is used to concatenate grouped values into a single array, not to concatenate arrays.

Comment: array_agg agregates rows to array - eg `select array_agg(oid) from pg_database`

Comment: array_agg is attempting to do this `array[array[1:18], array[1:24], array[1:48]]` and that is not valid multi dimensional array. You need to write your own aggregate that will concat arrays instead.

Comment: After looking into this further I see what it is doing: `array_agg({1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}) => {{1,4,7},{2,5,8},{3,6,9}}` is there an aggregate function that would concaternate so `?_agg({1},{2,3},{4,5,6}) => {1,2,3,4,5,6}`?

Comment: and I don't feel I complete understand why it is not [3:90] in the end..

Comment: for the above - array_agg unnested multidimentional array will concat as you want

Comment: How would you call this? I have tried `array_agg(unnest("array_col"))` and get `ERROR:  set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set`

Comment: @Derek You would have to use subselect on query that would unnest and produce row set, then array agg on that subselect. Or upgrade to pg10

Comment: Thank you. What does pg10 offer, I can't see anything in the documentation.

Comment: nvm, Just tested it on pg10 and it is actually still not possible without subselect :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Continuing from discussion in comments, my personal suggestion is to create aggregate.

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_concat_agg(anyarray) (
  SFUNC = array_cat,
  STYPE = anyarray
);
```

Then you can do this:

```
SELECT column1
  FROM (VALUES (array[1,2,3]), (array[3,4]), (array[53,43,33,22])) arr;
    column1
---------------
 {1,2,3}
 {3,4}
 {53,43,33,22}
(3 rows)

SELECT array_concat_agg(column1)
  FROM (VALUES (array[1,2,3]), (array[3,4]), (array[53,43,33,22])) arr;
    array_concat_agg
-------------------------
 {1,2,3,3,4,53,43,33,22}
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thank you. That is so simple that I wonder why this isn't a standard function.

Comment: If you're using v14+ you may need to tweak this. https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/3266664.1633045937%40sss.pgh.pa.us

Comment: It will work v14+ if you change it to: `CREATE or replace AGGREGATE array_concat_agg(anycompatiblearray) (
  SFUNC = array_cat,
  STYPE = anycompatiblearray
);` Otherwise could nest array_cats: `select array_cat(ARRAY[1,2,3], ARRAY[4,5])`