# Multiple distinct arrays with null values among them

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a table with three one dimensional arrays (and also a primary key and several other columns, but they do not matter). All of these arrays could be `NULL`. The arrays do overlap quite often in each column: Many values are in several arrays. I now want a query which returns one row with three arrays being the distinct values of the whole array column.

Creating the test table like so

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_array_test;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_array_test(id integer, my_txt text[], my_int1 integer[], my_int2 integer[]);
INSERT INTO my_array_test(id, my_txt, my_int1, my_int2) VALUES (1,'{text1,text2}','{1,2}','{21,22}');
INSERT INTO my_array_test(id, my_txt, my_int1, my_int2) VALUES (2,null,'{7,8}','{21,22}');
INSERT INTO my_array_test(id, my_txt, my_int1, my_int2) VALUES (3,'{text2,text4}',null,null);
INSERT INTO my_array_test(id, my_txt, my_int1, my_int2) VALUES (3,null,null,'{17,18}');
INSERT INTO my_array_test(id, my_txt, my_int1, my_int2) VALUES (4,'{text1,text2}','{1,2,3}','{21,22}');
INSERT INTO my_array_test(id, my_txt, my_int1, my_int2) VALUES (5,'{text1,text5}','{1,5}','{21,25}');
INSERT INTO my_array_test(id, my_txt, my_int1, my_int2) VALUES (6,null,null,null);
```

The result being something like

```
select * from my_array_test ;
 id |    my_txt     | my_int1 | my_int2
----+---------------+---------+---------
  1 | {text1,text2} | {1,2}   | {21,22}
  2 |               | {7,8}   | {21,22}
  3 | {text2,text4} |         |
  3 |               |         | {17,18}
  4 | {text1,text2} | {1,2,3} | {21,22}
  5 | {text1,text5} | {1,5}   | {21,25}
  6 |               |         |
(7 rows)
```

The expected result would be `{text1,text2,text4,text5},{1,2,7,8,2,5},{21,22,17,18,25}` (order within the array is not important.)

What I tried was a multiple lateral query like so:

```
SELECT 
    array_agg(DISTINCT t) AS text_array_result,
    array_agg(DISTINCT i1) AS integer_array1_result,
    array_agg(DISTINCT i2) AS integer_array2_result 
FROM 
    my_array_test,
    unnest(my_txt) AS t,
    unnest(my_int1) AS i1,
    unnest(my_int2) AS i2
```

However, that kills all values which are only in rows with `NULL` arrays among them.

I also tried `unnest(COALESCE(my_txt,'{}')) AS t,` and so on, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my custom aggregate described [in this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47319822/1995738)

```
select
    array_merge_agg(my_txt) AS text_array_result,
    array_merge_agg(my_int1) AS integer_array1_result,
    array_merge_agg(my_int2) AS integer_array2_result 
from 
    my_array_test;

     text_array_result     | integer_array1_result | integer_array2_result 
---------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------
 {text1,text2,text4,text5} | {1,2,3,5,7,8}         | {17,18,21,22,25}
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you want all distinct values, but null? then you can just [remove](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) `NULL`s. definetely does not look neat, but:

```
t=# with u as (select unnest(my_txt) a,unnest(my_int1) b,unnest(my_int2) v from my_array_test)
select array_remove(array_agg(distinct a),NULL),array_remove(array_agg(distinct b),NULL),array_remove(array_agg(distinct v),NULL) from u;
       array_remove        | array_remove  |   array_remove
---------------------------+---------------+------------------
 {text1,text2,text4,text5} | {1,2,3,5,7,8} | {17,18,21,22,25}
(1 row)
```

for pre10 version:

```
t=# SELECT
    array_remove(array_agg(DISTINCT t),NULL) AS text_array_result,
    array_remove(array_agg(DISTINCT i1),NULL) AS integer_array1_result,
    array_remove(array_agg(DISTINCT i2),NULL) AS integer_array2_result
FROM
    my_array_test
    left outer join unnest(my_txt) AS t on true
    left outer join unnest(my_int1) AS i1 on true
    left outer join unnest(my_int2) AS i2 on true
;
     text_array_result     | integer_array1_result | integer_array2_result
---------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------
 {text1,text2,text4,text5} | {1,2,3,5,7,8}         | {17,18,21,22,25}
(1 row)
```

Comment: Does that really work for you as you describe? For me, it doesn't. See fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/875ea/1 I get: "{text1,text2,text5}";"{1,2,3,5}";"{21,22,25}" - which is the same problem. Values within rows which contain NULL INSTEAD of an array are ignored. NULL values WITHIN an array would not matter. I think you tried to salve the latter phenomenon.

Comment: @cis frankly saying I'm suprised that inner join worked in my first example :) meanwhile http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/875ea/4 works