# Concatenate arrays of different sizes

Tags: arrays, postgresql, concatenation

How do I concatenate **ARRAYS** of different sizes ?
Tried :

```
 select array_agg(field) from table
```

but I'm getting this :

> ERROR:  cannot accumulate arrays of different dimensionality

```
table:

field
-----
{1,2,3}
{3,8}
{9,0,7,9,6}
{4}
...
```

expected result:

```
{1,2,3,3,8,9,0,7,9,6,4}
```

Comment: If you want to *concatenate* them, don't use `array_agg`, which tries to put them into a multidimensional array.

Comment: What data type is `field`, what do your values look like (an example table), and what result do you expect?

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output and a clear explaination

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer to my question :

[PostgreSQL array_agg(INTEGER[])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849237/postgresql-array-agginteger)

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_concat_agg(anyarray) (
  SFUNC = array_cat,
  STYPE = anyarray
);
```

from : Łukasz Kamiński